# Redirect issue with Slim 2.6 and Twig

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, twig, slim

On a local WAMP server, I've got a website built using Twig and Slim (as [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGKUvioJly40RJZchSG2-34)), which works without a hitch. However, when running on a remote server, there are redirect issues.

Namely, the line `$app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('home'))` in *app/routes/auth/register.php* gives a blank page with the following in the address bar 'scrumphd.dreamhosters.com/public/register', despite the fact that echoing `$app->urlFor('home')` gives '/public/'.

So far I've tried changing the url under *app->config->production.php* and also redirecting both to specified url's and other routes. I feel the problem may lie with the config file, with .htaccess, or with the *app/start.php* file. Unfortunately the web page doesn't render any error, so I'm finding it impossible to debug.

Here's the pesky register.php with the redirect at the end of the post route:

```
<?php

use PhD\User\UserPermission;

$app->get('/register', $guest(), function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('auth/register.php');
})->name('register');

$app->post('/register', $guest(), function() use ($app) {

    $request = $app->request;

    $email = $request->post('email');
    $username = $request->post('username');
    $password = $request->post('password');
    $passwordConfirm = $request->post('password_confirm');

    $v = $app->validation;

    $v->validate([
        'email' => [$email, 'required|email|uniqueEmail'],
        'username' => [$username, 'required|alnumDash|max(20)|uniqueUsername'],
        'password' => [$password, 'required|min(6)'],
        'password_confirm' => [$passwordConfirm, 'required|matches(password)']
    ]);

    if ($v->passes()) {

        $identifier = $app->randomlib->generateString(128);

        $user = $app->user->create([
            'email' => $email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $app->hash->password($password),
            'active' => false,
            'active_hash' => $app->hash->hash($identifier),
        ]);

        $user->permissions()->create(UserPermission::$defaults);

        $app->mail->send('email/auth/registered.php', ['user' => $user, 'identifier' => $identifier], function($message) use ($user) {
            $message->to($user->email);
            $message->subject('Thanks for registering.');
        });

        $app->mail->send('email/auth/notification.php', ['user' => $user], function($message) use ($user) {
            $message->to('james.clarke11@imperial.ac.uk');
            $message->subject('New registered user!');
        });

        $app->flash('global', 'You have been registered.');
        $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));
    }

    $app->render('auth/register.php', [
        'errors' => $v->errors(),
        'request' => $request
    ]);





})->name('register.post');
```

The full code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jimmyclarke01/Scrumphd).

Any ideas and help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use ``$app->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));``. or even a ``return $app->redi..`` that the content get not rendered?

Comment: I've tried the latter, but I'm not sure about the former. I'll try it and leave an update on whether it works.